# How to extract specific fields from ETW packet when struct and arrays are involved

Tags: c++, winapi, etw

I'm writting a C++ application to trace certain fields within specific ETW packets. specifically, `Microsoft-Windows-USB-USB3HUB`. From all examples I've managed to put my hands on, the proper way is to first make a `recursive-look-like` search within the buffer, and print the fields one by one respectfully to its type, There are more than 20 types within the `_TDH_OUT_TYPE` enum.

So given the following packet:
[image]

Theoretically, How do i extract and save `Fid_PortNumber`'s `Fid_PortPath[0]`'s & `Fid_PortPath[1]`'s values without re-implementing a `VARIANT` like member to store any kind of variables' types?

In addition, i'd like to extract other types of events, with different types of fields and structure. What's the right approach for this problem, How to i serialize the ETW packet into a workable c++ interface / struct?

Edit: Code taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee441329(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: How are you currently processing ETW packets? I searched online but I can't find any definition for `Microsoft-Windows-USB-USB3HUB` or `_TDH_OUT_TYPE` (I do see `TdhOutType` in the Linq-to-Events project on Github though). Can you post whatever code you have right now? How are you displaying the packet for that screenshot? (It doesn't look like Visual Studio or VS Code's debugger).

Comment: Done, I guess i also have to somehow utilize event's manifest